# Using ApplicationWindow in qml with PyQt5 results in a blank window, but the same code without it doesn't

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qml

I am trying to write a simple Hello World app in PyQt5 using qml.

This is my code with

```
import QtQuick 2.0

    
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 500
    title: "Hello App"

    Rectangle {
        width: 400; height: 500
        color: "gray"

        Text {
            id: helloworld
            text: "Hello world!"
            color: "blue"
            font.pointSize: 32
        }
    }
}
```

This results in a blank window.

This code is my code without ApplicationWindow, and this one works:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 400; height: 500
    color: "gray"
     Text {
        id: helloworld
        text: "Hello world!"
        color: "blue"
        font.pointSize: 32
    }
}
```

Why is using ApplicationWindow breaking the code?

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrlfrom PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

view = QQuickView()
view.setSource(QUrl("file2_working.qml"))
view.show()

app.exec()
```

Comment: please share the python code

Comment: Added the python code!

Comment: If you want to use ApplicationWindow then you must use QQmlApplicationEngine.

Comment: @eyllanesc how do I do that?

Comment: see the duplicates questions